# Does this $0-1$ integer program have any speciallity?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, binary-programming

Given matrix $A \in \{0,1\}^{m \times n}$ and vector $b \in (\mathbb{Z^+})^m$, where $\mathbb{Z^+}$ is the set of positive integers,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & c^T x\\ \text{subject to} & Ax \leq b\\ & x \geq 0\\ & x \in \{0,1\}^n\end{array}$$

Notice the biggest difference from normal $0-1$ integer programming is that 
$A \in \{0,1\}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in (\mathbb{Z^+})^m$. Is there anything special about such integer programs? Is there an algorithm to solve them in polynomial time?

Comment: The way you have written the formulation, it looks like $A$ and $b$ are variables, but I think you meant them to be constants.

Comment: @RobPratt Yes, and they are constant interges, and A are all zero or one integers

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo agree.

Comment: Now posted also at https://or.stackexchange.com/q/2770/8

Comment: Interesting how much more warmly the question was received at OR SE.